# Selecting all characters with regex until a specific word

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have a document as follows:

```
1. Question text
A) some words
B) some words
multiline text
multiline text
multiline text
(Answer A)
2. Question text
A) some words
B) some words
multiline text
multiline text
multiline text
(Answer B)
3. Question text
A) some words
B) some words
multiline text
multiline text
multiline text
(Answer A)
```

I am trying to remove all multiline text between every line with B) and question lines. So at the and it should look like this:

```
1. Question text
A) some words
B) some words
(Answer A)

2. Question text
A) some words
B) some words
(Answer B)

3. Question text
A) some words
B) some words
(Answer A)
```

I used the following regex: `B\).*\n[^w]+\(Answer`, but it selects all characters between first line with `B)` until the last occurrence of 
`(Answer`, instead of what I am trying to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find: `^B\).*\R\K[\s\S]*?(\([^)]+\))`
- Replace: `$1\n`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^B\)            : literally B), at beginning of line
.*\R            : 0 or more any character, followed by any kind of newline
\K              : forget all we have seen until this position
[\s\S]*?        : 0 or more any character (including linebreak), not greedy
(               : start group 1
  \(            : open parenthesis
    [^)]+       : 1 or more any character that is not a close parenthesis
  \)            : close parenthesis
)               : end group 1
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1      : content of group 1 (ie. the answer)
\n      : a linebreak, you could use \r\n if necessary.
```

**Result for given example:**

```
1. Question text
A) some words
B) some words
(Answer A)

2. Question text
A) some words
B) some words
(Answer B)

3. Question text
A) some words
B) some words
(Answer A)
```